# java keystroke method call

Tags: java, keystroke

I have tried multiple times to find out a solution on my own by consulting Google, but this question, as ridiculously easy as it seems, has no documented answer. It seems to me.

All I want to know is: How to call a method from a keystroke?
Example: Pressing ctrl + up -> call method zoomUp();

ps: would be nice if that keystroke could be bound to a JTextPane.

**Update**

Until now my solution was to:

- Create an Item: `JMenuItem up = new JMenuItem("up");`
- Create a shortcut:

> up.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_UP,
>   Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getMenuShortcutKeyMask()));

- Catch the event by a listener:

> up.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {    public
>   void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
>         //Do stuff    } });

(- never add the Item so it is a hidden shortcut)
But this is obviously ridiculous.

Comment: Relevant (?) swing tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: Use a keylistener: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JTextFieldaddKeyListenerKeyListenerl.htm

Comment: Well thank you for the response, but I don't think a keyListener is the right solution for me. I don't need to check one key press/release. I need a keystroke = a key with a modifier like ctrl.

Comment: Key listener supports keys like Ctrl and Alt

Comment: @Haeri Compile and run the tutorial in the link above. You'll see it prints both keys and modifiers. Also, your comment makes me think you shouldn't claim there's *"no documented answer"* before [you've actually tried some of them](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @blgt2 Ok you are right. It does appear to have a ctrl modifier. But I have the (probably wrong) impression that this is not how the keylistener is supposed to be used. And "no documented answer" is just a fragment of an answer where at the end I state "It seems to me." which implies that anything I said before could very well be wrong. But I don't want to get into a deep discussion because of a simple question. And please take a look at the updated op.

Comment: @Haeri I understand where you're coming from, I'm merely pointing out the fact we can't really help if you don't give more details than that "it seems so". *Why* does it seem so? Did you give it a go? What error did you get? These are all questions you need to answer to make the original question answerable. Right now it's more than a little too vague. (e.g. the update says it's *obviously riduculous* -- no, it isn't, unless you elaborate)

Comment: @blgt ok. I was thinking that the update made it clear, but I could try to elaborate a bit more on what I don't like about my current solution. I want to go from A to B. The current solution makes it so that I go From A to C then D then X then PI and finally to B. Its too many unnecessary lines of code, so I am asking for the (How it actually should be done) solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `JMenuItem` to create "hidden" short cuts. The short cuts of `JMenuItem`s become active once the `JMenuItem` gets indirectly added to a `Window` (usually via <-`JMenu`<-`JMenuBar`<-`JFrame`). Without that link, it cannot be known whether or not the accelerator is to be triggered or not, as the same accelerator might trigger different actions in different application windows.

You need to use a `KeyListener` on the component or frame in which you want to react.

Comment: Ok thank you for clearing that up. Like I said I was under the impression that a KeyListener was meant for "game" type of inputs, like the ones in a while(true) loop. And I only need to us it once in a lifetime to zoom in/out the JTextPane. But Ok I am going to look into that KeyListener again.